# Which property of Hyper-V WMI classes to access memory info

Tags: windows, memory, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I want to get memory of a virtual machine with Hyper-V WMI Classes.
There are 4 memory classes; but I could not find any properties of them to get memory value.

Msvm_Memory class have *BlockSize* and *NumberOfBlocks* properties.
When I multiply them, I could not get correct memory.

Respect to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850175(v=vs.85).aspx It is already wrong approach.

> BlockSize
>   Data type: uint64
>   Access type: Read-only
>   The size, in bytes, of the blocks that form the storage extent. If variable block size, then the maximum block size, in bytes, should be specified. If the block size is unknown, or if a block concept is not valid (for example, for aggregate extents, memory, or logical disks), enter a 1 (one). This property is inherited from CIM_StorageExtent, and it is always set to 1048576.

Which class and property should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Msvm_MemorySettingData` class to access the defined memory properties of an instance. You may filter the results by `InstanceID` and parse `AllocationUnits` together with `Limit` to get the configured maximum memory amount.

In the following case there is 1 TB of memory that can be allocated for the specific instance "`4764334E-E001-4176-82EE-5594EC9B530E`".

```
Example InstanceID: "Microsoft:Definition\\4764334E-E001-4176-82EE-5594EC9B530E\\Default"
AllocationUnits: "bytes * 2^20"
Limit: 1048576
```

Msvm_MemorySettingData: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850176(v=vs.85).aspx